# Ruby : Watir : How to Avoid program termination from Watir::Exception::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webdriver, watir

**I get the following error on Ruby Watir Program. How to Avoid from closing the browser ?**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from index.rb:29:in `<main>'
        8: from index.rb:29:in `each'
        7: from index.rb:33:in `block in <main>'
        6: from index.rb:33:in `each'
        5: from index.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:65:in `exists?'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:716:in `assert_exists'
        2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:611:in `locate'
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/lib/watir/elements/element.rb:723:in `ensure_context'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/watir-6.16.5/
```

lib/watir/browser.rb:260:in `locate': 
browser was closed (Watir::Exception::Error)

Comment: post the code so that we can check it.

Comment: kindly post the code as well which is throwing error.